# Why did I get an email thanking me for participating in an ongoing beta on Arqade Meta?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email

I got an email today thanking me for participating in the ongoing beta for Arqade Meta, and congratulating me for making the [leaderboard](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/42/alltime/gaming-meta) which is a nonexistant page. Does this have something to do with the responsive design updates, or was it just a bug that the email was sent? As far as I know, meta sites aren't supposed to send these emails, and Arqade isn't in beta.

[image]

Comment: I got one, too.

Comment: These mails were sent by accident. Official explanation will (probably) follow.

Comment: Well, maybe because you are awesome and ... earned a lot of reputation on meta?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this!

We had a hiccup where the chunk of code that excludes meta sites from these emails got removed accidentally - oops! A few different sites had these emails go out, including Arqade, Information Security, and Software Engineering. That's been fixed now, so it shouldn't be a problem moving forward.

Apologies for any inconvenience!

Comment: http://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2013/11/24/simply-explained